# Local web service for dynamic connecting to remote computers services over ssh

Tags: ssh, routing, web

Lets say, that I have multiple machines with multiple webservices running, all machines behind (different) ssh connecting route(s).

Does there exist a localhost service (webapp running at my own pc for example at localhost:8080/service) I could use, that would:
- given url (or something like) localhost:8080/service/my.ssh.server_sshserversport/remoteserviceport

... would display me (in my local browser) the contents of my.ssh.server's port 'remoteport'

.... or would need me to provide credentials (in the web browser) if Iam not connected?

- I dont want manually edit ssh port forwarding for each machine (also then 2 services running at the same ports at 2 machines would need 2 different local ports)
- I look at it more from the point of view of my machine - to say specifically I want to install one thing at my own pc and let the other computers with webservices be as they are
- Iam not looking for across-the-internet solution, it would be cool if it would be an app running on my own pc, that would work without external world.

Also If there is no such service, what tool would you recommend to programm my own server, that would do exactly this?

Answer (score 0):

One option is [ngrok - secure introspectable tunnels to localhost](https://ngrok.com/).

The free version is limited to a single remote instance though - for tunneling more than one local port and having a fixed address you'll need to use the commercial version.

Given a local server on a known port ngrok gives you a web address to access the server remotely.

Comment: Also it seems it is not a local solution. Any solutions that would be local?

Comment: Khaj maybe I didn't understand your question correctly. @roaima the free version has proven very useful - but yes, it does have a commercial version.

Comment: You are correct @roaima. I see now it won't work for multiple machines. I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: @YodaSholtz - maybe I didnt formulate it correctly ;) I have updated the description, but to summarize it here - Lets say, that the ssh happens on intranet AND that the machines (that are behind the ssh) cannot have anything installed to them - i can touch only my own pc ... or I can make my own web app running at localhost.